# Entity Framework Core v6.0.5 foreign key properties returning unexpected null

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I read a `LoginUser` (an extension of `IdentityUser`) from the `AspNetUsers` table with Entity Framework Core v6.0.5.

When I attempt to read its foreign key property `Company`, the property is always null - why?

i.e.

```
var user = dbContext.Users
                    .FirstOrDefault(...);// A non-null LoginUser is returned

var companyId = user.CompanyId; // results in Integer 1 - as expected

var company = user.Company; // company is always null
```

Table definitions:

```
public class LoginUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; } = -1;
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public virtual ICollection<LoginUser> LoginUsers { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string TradingName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

A foreign key index exists on the `LoginUser` table generated for the column `CompanyId`.

Any ideas what I have omitted to do?

`AspNetUsers` table data:

```
Id                                      CompanyId   Other User fields not shown...
8c568150-ecf8-46f4-8ec1-db9a7a66daaa    1
```

Companies table data:

```
Id  TradingName 
-----------------------
-1  Unassigned Company
1   Discovery
```

Comment: `dbContext.Users.Include(x => x.Company).FirstOrDefault(...)`. EF do not load whole database.

Comment: I thought the Include Lamdba was for Eager Loading? I have used the virtual keyword to indicate Lazy Loading?

Comment: To enable Lazy loading, which I do not recommend, you have to use [UseLazyLoadingProxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy#lazy-loading-with-proxies)

Comment: Lazy Loading introduces N+1 query problem, instead of `Include`, which loads data in one batch.